# Работа с архивом 7z в c++ builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, 7z

В c++ builder есть простая форма, где пользователь может выбрать 7z архив. Необходимо по нажатию кнопки изменить определённый файле в выбранном архиве.

Может, я неправильно гуглю, но не смог найти ни одного туториала как это сделать. Везде пишут про lzma, но нигде ни слова про то, как эту библиотеку подключить и как с ней работать. Хотелось бы либо подробных разъяснений что и как сделать, либо ссылку туда, где они есть

Заранее спасибо

Comment: А в документацию (хотя бы и скудную) lzma вы заглядывали?

Comment: @VTT, в первую очередь, не нашёл там ничего, что помогло бы мне

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть [TSevenZipVCL](http://www.rg-software.de/),
Есть JclCompression из [JCL: JEDI Code Library](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JEDI_Code_Library) 
Выбирай по вкусу. :)